# Check if application exists on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can I check whether an application exists on iphone programmatically if I know the name of application (without using URL scheme)?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that unless the device is jail broken.... (assuming that you are talking about iOS)

Comment: I have seen something like this done In @UseClear app. It gives you hidden schemes if you have certain other apps installed. I've always wondered how they did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to check for existens of an Application is to check if the device can responds to a specific URL-Scheme, which the Application must have registered. Example of this is the native Facebook Application. If this is not the case, you are out of luck.